# ng-pattern directive mess up input's capability

Tags: angularjs

I need to validate with `ng-pattern` that security code has exactly 4 digits. After I add `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{4}$/"` input fails to display model attribute (security code). If I remove `ng-pattern` then form and input works but no validation. How to fix it?

http://jsbin.com/saroyo/1/

Comment: I think is better to use ng-minlenght and and ng-maxlenght having both equal to 4 and only check that the 4 charactes is numbers, I will create a fiddle.

Comment: when switched to Angular 1.3.3 it works fine.....strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with only one error visible

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){

});
```

```html
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name="myForm">
    Code: <input type="number " name="code" ng-model="user.code"
      ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="4">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.code.$error.minlength">
      Should be 4 charachters long</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.code.$error.maxlength">
      Should be 4 charachters long</span><br>
    <span class="error" ng-model="user.code" ng-show="(user.code === parseInt(user.code, 10)) && (myForm.$dirty === true) && (myForm.code.$error.minlength == false) && (myForm.code.$error.maxlength == false)">
      Should have only integers</span><br>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```